# Issue with SSH after migration from Amazon Linux to Ubuntu (EC2)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a script that starts and stops tinyproxy on my EC2 instance.
The core of the script (in addition to some networking on my side) are 2 commands:

```
ssh -t $PROXY_HOST sudo '/etc/init.d/tinyproxy start'
ssh -t $PROXY_HOST sudo '/etc/init.d/tinyproxy stop'
```

where $PROXY_HOST is configured in ~/.ssh/confing

```
host MyHost
    HostName <real ip here>
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile <path is here>
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    ServerAliveCountMax 4
```

Everything was fine on Amazon Linux, however after migration to Ubuntu there is a problem now:

- both scripts to start/stop tinyproxy work locally on EC2 machine
- stop script works remotely just like on Amazon Linux - there are no running tinyproxy processes after execution
- start script DOESN'T work remotely

EC2 AMI is based on ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server

Any hints about where do I start digging?

PS. Yes, I changed default user from ec2-user to ubuntu in ~/.ssh/config after migration

**Edit: Added information as asked by muru**

The output of local and remote runs are identical

```
+ PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
  + CONFIG=/etc/tinyproxy.conf
  + DAEMON=/usr/sbin/tinyproxy
  + DESC=tinyproxy
  + FLAGS=
  + NAME=tinyproxy
  + [ -r /etc/default/tinyproxy ]
  + test -f /usr/sbin/tinyproxy
  + set -e
  + [ start != stop ]
  + [ -f /etc/tinyproxy.conf ]
  + awk {print $2}
  + grep -i ^User[[:space:]] /etc/tinyproxy.conf
  + USER=nobody
  + awk {print $2}
  + grep -i ^Group[[:space:]] /etc/tinyproxy.conf
  + GROUP=nogroup
  + sed -e s/"//g
  + awk {print $2}
  + grep -i ^PidFile[[:space:]] /etc/tinyproxy.conf
  + PIDFILE=/var/run/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.pid
  + dirname /var/run/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.pid
  + PIDDIR=/var/run/tinyproxy
  + [ -n /var/run/tinyproxy -a /var/run/tinyproxy != /var/run ]
  + [ ! -d /var/run/tinyproxy ]
  + [ nobody ]
  + chown nobody /var/run/tinyproxy
  + [ nogroup ]
  + chgrp nogroup /var/run/tinyproxy
  + echo -n Starting tinyproxy:⋅
  Starting tinyproxy: + start-stop-daemon --start --quiet -o --exec /usr/sbin/tinyproxy --
  + echo tinyproxy.
  tinyproxy.
  + exit 0
```

Comment: What happens when you do `ssh -t $PROXY_HOST sudo /etc/init.d/tinyproxy start`? Any output? Add the output of `ssh -t $PROXY_HOST sudo sh -x /etc/init.d/tinyproxy start` to your post.

Comment: @muru thanks for the hint, compared local and remote runs, added info

Comment: Looks the init script itself is working fine. Look into tinyproxy's logs: ` /var/log/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.log`

Comment: @muru did it in the very beginning - logs are just empty in case of remote run

Comment: Then I suppose the only thing left to do is to run `tinyproxy` manually: `sudo -iu nobody tinyproxy -d` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @muru - running manually via ssh works just fine (and this is surprising)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is some difference in default handling of SIGHUP between Amazon Linux and Ubuntu 14.04 on EC2. So, basically adding *nohup* resolves the issue:

```
ssh -t $PROXY_HOST sudo 'nohup /etc/init.d/tinyproxy start'
```